# PhP Array Pulling Columns and Values Array Munupulation

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Ok I got an array like so. How do I take all the values in color to perform a sql statement.
For example how do I get FROM var1,var2,.... etc.
I can do an array implode and add commas but I do I get all the values for colors?
Thanks in advance.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [colors] => var1
        [testType] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [colors] => var2
        [testType] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [colors] => var3
        [testType] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [colors] => var4
        [testType] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [colors] => var5
        [testType] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [colors] => var6
        [testType] => 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [colors] => var7
        [testType] => 1
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [colors] => var8
        [testType] => 1
    )

)
```

Comment: Is `munupulation` like `copulation` or something else?

Comment: I probably used the wrong word for it. I just wanted to take the colors out from the array, and the array is generated via a query from the db. I guess what I meant to say was I want to manupulate the array in a certain way so that it can be used. Are you good with loops? Kinda stuck here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478402/looping-php-array-loops-through-database-query-to-output-result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 5.3+, you can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to fetch all the relevant indexes in your nested arrays.  Then you can generate your SQL using string operations @AbraCadaver has used.  I am also bored.

```
$colors = array_map(function ($sub_arr) {return $sub_arr['colors'];}, $arr);
```

Comment: danronmoon:  It is giving me a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' "

Comment: Fixed.  Was too lazy to have it parse properly

Comment: Got it! You are a genius! How do you use testType as keys for that array? Watch Naruto if you are bored.

Answer (score 2):

PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$list = "'" . implode("','", array_column($array, 'colors')) . "'";
```

It would've been nice to see your attempt, but I was bored.

Comment: Sorry I tried several attempts but I am using php 5.3. I did see array_column function :(